# Insert en 2 tablas con last_insert_id()

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Buen día, 
estoy intentando realizar un insert en 2 tablas que están relacionadas por el ID principal de una que es la FK de la otra. Estoy usando un *Stored Procedure* para esto, pero me aparece un error cuando intento cargar datos que es: *Column count doesn't match value count at row 1*.

Aquí les añado mi *Stored Procedure*.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Informacion`(
                 //Tabla1

        in _dato1 varchar(100),
        in _dato2 varchar(100), 
        in _dato3 varchar(100), 
        in _fecha date,
                //Tabla 2

        in _dato4 varchar(100),
        in _dato5 varchar(100),
        in _dato6 varchar(100),
        in _tabla1_FK int(11)

)
BEGIN
Insert into tabla1 values(_dato1, _dato2, _dato3, curdate());
Insert into tabla2 values(_dato4, _dato5, _dato6, last_insert_id());
SELECT MAX(idtabla1) from tabla1;
END
```

Digamos que en el parametro *_tabla1_FK* debería ir el valor del id de la tabla1.

No sé si el error se encuentra en los parametros declarados al inicio (donde no menciono el id de ambas tablas ya que estos son autoincrementales) o en el uso del *last_insert_id()*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está en la sintaxis del `INSERT` que empleas:

```
Insert into tabla1 values(_dato1, _dato2, _dato3, curdate());
Insert into tabla2 values(_dato4, _dato5, _dato6, last_insert_id());
```

En ambos casos, no estás especificando de forma explícita las columnas a las que le vas a asignar valor. En este caso, MySQL espera que le suministres valores para todas las columnas de la tabla. Pero por tu descripción, entiendo que en realidad estás omitiendo la columna autoincrementable.

La solución es de nombrar de forma explícita las columnas a las que le estás asignando valor en el `INSERT`. Algo así:

```
Insert into tabla1 (dato1, dato2, dato3, fecha) values(_dato1, _dato2, _dato3, curdate());
Insert into tabla2 (dato4, dato5, dato6, fk_id) values(_dato4, _dato5, _dato6, last_insert_id());
```

Claro, yo no conzco los nombres de las columnas de tus tablas. Así que reemplaza:

```
(dato1, dato2, dato3, fecha)
(dato4, dato5, dato6, fk_id)
```

... con los nombres de verdad en tus tablas.

Comment: Funciona fantástico, muchas gracias por la ayuda y por tu tiempo. Buen día :D